# How to covert curl into a python code with native library 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, curl

How do i convert the below curl  into python code.
I am confused on how to include the api key, i know what value it should be.
The python code must only contain native libraries

```
curl -G -H "api_key: YOUR_API_KEY" https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products --data-urlencode 'q={"search":"apple iphone"}'
```

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code translation service. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and convenient way is to use requests library in python.
Just import the requests library and you can do all REST operations

Example:-

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Please follow below guide. Very convenient to use.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: following the guide would it be like this...                                           payload = {'api_key': 'value1', 'q' = {'search', 'apple iphone']}

>>> r = requests.get(https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products ', params=payload)
>>> print(r.url)

Comment: if you want to skip using this library, you can use import subprocess. ; pipe = subprocess.PIPE ; proc = subprocess.Popen(CURL_COMMAND, shell=True, stdin=pipe, stdout=pipe, stderr=pipe); proc.returncode;

Answer (score -1):

i am going to use the requests library.
I can send the request
but i caannot send the same api key that works when i curl as it comes with an error message invalid api

the python  code... which throws up invalid api key error despite using the same key as curl code

```
import requests

payload = {'api_key:SEM3DC0261ECC65764A9F8B2B8008F16XXXX' 'q': {'search', 'apple iphone'}}

r = requests.get('https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products ', params=payload)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

curl code which works fine

```
curl -G -H "api_key: SEM3DC0261ECC65764A9F8B2B8008F16XXXX" https://api.semantics3.com/test/v1/products --data-urlencode 'q={"search":"apple iphone"}'
```

The api keys are partially blanked out

What can i do?

Thanks Daniel

Comment: `api_key` is sent as header, not part of the payload, python code is not correct